# Equality of two topological spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Suppose $(X, T_1), (X, T_2)$ be two topological spaces. It is given that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ is convergent in $T_1$ if and only if it is convergent in $T_2.$  Does this imply $T_1= T_2\;$
?
If not, I can't find any counterexamples.

Comment: Do sequences converge vacuously in a topology which isn't metrizable? Or are you allowing sequences defined by nets, etc?

Comment: A sequence {xn} in (X,T) is convergent to some x in X if for any open U containing x, there is some m in natural numbers such that xn is in U for all n>m.

Comment: How about $X=\Bbb R$, $T_1$ is the set of intervals $(-s, s)$, and $T_2$ is the subset of $T_1$ where $s=\frac1k$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is negative. Consider two topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ in $\mathbb R$:

- $\tau_1$ is the discrete topology;
- $\tau_2$ is the topology for which a set $S\neq\mathbb R$ is closed if and only if $S$ is finite or countable.

Obviously, $\tau_1\neq\tau_2$. Now, prove that the convergent sequences are the same in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_1)$ and in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

consider $\omega_1+1$ with the order topology $\tau$, and the topology generated by $\tau\cup\{\{\omega_1\}\}$.